# Google App Engine RPC Service

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, rpc

I've created an application using Google Web Toolkit and Google App Engine that saves objects based on user selections into a RPC Service Implementation.

It was my understanding that everytime GWT "creates" this service, the data is reinstantiated with the default values. Unfortunately it seems like when a user on one computer saves a change to the data, another user on another computer is seeing the data change on their end. Im not using a datastore or anything so why is this happening?

EDIT: After some research I am seeing that I need to use sessions to handle the delivery of the objects. However, in my RemoteServiceServlet I am calling this.getThreadLocalRequest and it's returning null. **Why does this.getThreadLocalRequest() return null??**

UPDATE: Answering my own questions here : ) You cannot getThreadLocalRequest() in the constructor of your Servlet. duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling `getThreadLocalRequest()` in the constructor of my servlet. Good thing to be aware of - the local request doesnt happen until the servlet is loaded.